# Inserting related data in tables is slower than expected

Tags: c#, mysql, foreach

I created a program which records list of family.

The records are written from an index card.

In the index card. It contains the Ancestor and its relative.

I have two tables

**table 1**

> Information about the ancestor, like name, ID (auto increment), filename, username(the one in the PC)

**table 2**

> Information about the relatives, like name, ancestor_id(from table 1)

There are 20 people using the program. So i need to get the ID generated when the ancestor is inserted before inserting the relatives.

sometimes there are 10 relatives in the index. and sometimes there are 20

this is my stored procedure

```
INSERT INTO tbl_ancestor(an,`as`, dd, cn, su, mm, stn, re, yy, st,  filename, username, `zipName`, `batchName`, `folderName`, `remark`) 
        VALUES(_an, _as, _dd, _cn, _su, _mm, _stn, _re, _yy, _st, _fname, _username, _zipName, _batchName, _folderName, _remark);
        SELECT ID, filename, username, zipName, batchName, foldername FROM tbl_ancestor;
```

But when the record in the database becomes `10000` it waits for 5 seconds for the message to prompt that the data has been saved.

I only use select statement. Because i thought it will help me solve the problem if i use a `linq` in my c# code to get the ID of that ancestor to be used my the relatives. But the speed is the same.

Is this an error in my query?

or in my c# codes?

```
foreach (var item in tag.RelativeList)
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_insert_relative", conn)
    {
        CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    })
    {
        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_ancestor_id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_rgn", item.RGN);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_rsn", item.RSN);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_sgn", item.SGN);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_ssn", item.SN);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_username", tag.Username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_fname", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(tag.FileName));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this? To make my program faster? I can't think of a way to solve it. I've been searching also. But i can't find a concrete solution. Or maybe i'm using a wrong search keyword?

Comment: an orm like ef core generally makes sure or helps make sure that such things are added in the fastest possible way.

Answer (score 0):

```
          using (MySqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
          {
              foreach (var item in tag.RelativeList)
              {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_insert_relative",conn)
        {
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        })
        {
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_ancestor_id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_rgn", item.RGN);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_rsn", item.RSN);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_sgn", item.SGN);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_ssn", item.SN);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_username", tag.Username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_fname", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(tag.FileName));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
trans.commit
    }
}
```

You can use MysqlTransaction To fasten the insertion OR update a data into your Database.